# Convert complex list of lists to list of data frames

Tags: r, list, split

I have a complex list that consists of other lists and data frames. I need to simplify this list to consist only from data frames - so each second level list should be made into separate first level data frames.

Here is reproducible example:

```
 dd<-data.frame(x=1:3,y=4:6)
 l1<-list(dd,list(dd,dd))
 #original list
 l1
[[1]]
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

[[2]][[2]]
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

Result I need to get

```
 l2<-list(dd,dd,dd)
 l2
[[1]]
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

[[2]]
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

[[3]]
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

I tried with the function `unlist()` and argument `recursive=FALSE` but in this case first level data frame is converted to two vectors.

```
 unlist(l1,recursive=FALSE)
$x
[1] 1 2 3

$y
[1] 4 5 6

[[3]]
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

[[4]]
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way I could think of is to check if the class of input (while running `lapply`) is `data.frame` or `list`, and if it's a `data.frame` convert it to a list of `data.frame`. This'll result the entire list becoming list of list of data.frames. Then you can use `unlist` with `recursive=FALSE` as follows:

```
unlist(lapply(l1, function(x) 
      if (class(x) == "data.frame") list(x) else x), recursive=FALSE)
[[1]]
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

[[2]]
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

[[3]]
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

This works of course when the data is as you mention exactly. They are either list of data.frames or list of list of data.frames. Oh and welcome to SO (first question)! :)

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking all the time in opposite direction - how to split list of list. Idea to convert data frame to list of data frame is great.

Comment: I would try to avoid `class(x) == "data.frame"` and use `is.data.frame` instead.

Comment: not sure what's the problem here to avoid using it. could you elaborate? `is.data.frame` uses `inherits` internally and it'd give TRUE for objects derived from `data.frame`. For example on `data.table` as well. If that's desirable, then yes, using `inherits` is better.

Comment: Also `data.frame(rbind.fill.matrix(lst))` can coerce lists of matching format items into a single data.frame.

Comment: @geotheory Yes but I don't need to coerce separate data frame in to single data frame.

Comment: Certainly in the provided example it is not a problem. But like you said, it occurs quite often that `data.frames` also have other classes, such as `data.table`. For most applications it would probably be undesirable to unlist a `data.table`. I tend to avoid `class(x) == data.frame`, so I can reuse my code in a similar situation when I work with data.tables instead of data.frames. Moreover, `class(x) == data.table` will be `c(TRUE, FALSE)` if x is a `data.table`, which certainly would not be what you want.